# Joining on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:
`table_1` :

```
  NAME VALUES_WANTED
  A-1  value_1
  A-1  value_2
  A-1  value_3
  A-1  value_4
  A-1  value_5
  A-2  value_1
  A-2  value_2
  A-2  value_3
  A-2  value_4
  A-2  value_5
```

and  `table_2`:

```
  NAME VALUES   TAGS
  A-1  value_1  a
  A-1  value_2  aa
  A-1  value_3  s
  A-1  value_4  b
  A-1  value_y  e
  A-1  value_x  sd
  A-2  value_1  g
  A-2  value_2  fe
  A-2  value_3  k
  A-2  value_5  m
```

I want to get the following table:

```
  NAME VALUES_WANTED   TAGS
  A-1  value_1         a
  A-1  value_2         aa
  A-1  value_3         s
  A-1  value_4         b
  A-1  value_5         Null
  A-2  value_1         g
  A-2  value_2         fe
  A-2  value_3         k
  A-2  value_4         Null
  A-2  value_5         m
```

Basically, it is smth like lookup of  `TAGS` for  `VALUES_WANTED`. If the `VALUES_WANTED` is missing in `table_2`, it should return `Null` for its `TAGS`.

I know I need to join on `NAME` and `VALUES`. Have been trying different ways of `JOIN` like the following, but still failing...

```
SELECT a.NAME, a.VALUES, a.TAGS, s.VALUES_WANTED
FROM table_2 a


RIGHT JOIN table_1 s 
ON a.NAME = s.NAME 
AND a.VALUES = s.VALUES_WANTED
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: use `table1 LEFT JOIN table2`

Comment: that must the same as ```table_2 RIGHT JOIN table_1``` which is I am doing... or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a `left join` on the two columns:

```
SELECT t1.NAME, t1.VALUES_WANTED, t2.TAGS
FROM table_1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table_2 t2 
     ON t1.NAME = t2.NAME AND t1.VALUES_WANTED = t2.VALUES;
```

In a `LEFT JOIN`, all rows from the first table are kept along with matching rows from the second table.  That appears to be what you want.

You *can* also write this using a `RIGHT JOIN`, but I don't recommend that -- most people find it easier to read the `FROM` clause when they know what rows are needed.

Your version is close, but you are not selecting the right columns.  You have `a.Name` in the result set, but that will be `NULL` when there is not a match.

Answer (score 1):

use left join

```
SELECT a.NAME, a.VALUES_WANTED, b.TAGS
FROM table_1 a
left JOIN table_2 b 
ON a.NAME = b.NAME 
AND a.VALUES = b.VALUES_WANTED
```